# How to edit bash text file using sed

Tags: bash, sed, edit

genius:johnny bravo:56.80:100:38

hello:jack john:89.10:290:189

i have the above 2 lines inside my text file test.txt
i wish to change the last value, in this case 189 to 50, if user enters field 1 and field 2 correctly.

what i've done but isn't working

```
read title # genius/joker
read name  # jonny bravo or jack john
echo "enter new value"
read newValue
sed -i "s/^\($title:$name:[^:]*\):[^:]*:/\1:$newValue:/" test.txt
```

from my sed, i realize that the 4th field of code is change, in this case 290 is changed to new value instead of 189. 
Can any of you enlighten me on where did i go wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is incorrect. Try this:

```
sed -i "s/^\($title:$name:.*\):.*$/\1:$newValue/" test.txt
```

Comment: thanks! that worked, could u mind explaining this line in detail? i wish to understand the regex more. thanks alot!

Comment: I'm sure you can figure it out since it is a simpler regex than yours :) We're trying to match everything upto the last `:` which is what the `.*:` does. Then we match the rest of it using `:.*$`. Let me know if there is any specific detail which is unclear.

Comment: oh i see, thanks for the input, i'm still quite new to this coding style so i'm doing while learning. thanks for the explaination

Answer (score 4):

awk suites better for this case:

```
title="hello"
name="jack john"
n=50
awk -v f1="$title" -v f2="$name" -v n=$n -F: '$1==f1 && $2==f2{$NF=n}1' OFS=: file
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
genius:johnny bravo:56.80:100:38
hello:jack john:89.10:290:50
```

Comment: hey there, thanks for the reply, i realise that awk is a preferred option in doing this, but is there a way to do it by sed? Its kind of a requirement, as well as a learning point. 
thanks!